# How to set choice values in twig?

Tags: twig, html-select, symfony

I am using a `ChoiceType` in a Symfony3 form type

```
$builder
    ->add('confirmation', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'Maybe' => null,
            'Yes' => true,
            'No' => false,
        )
))
```

Now I want to set `choices` dynamically in twig. I would assume to go like this

```
{{ form_widget(field.type, {'choices': {'foo': true, 'bar': false}}) }}
```

but that throws error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("attr") on a boolean variable ("1") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 82

Is there any way to set choices in twig (while rendering the form field using `form_widget()` or `form_row()`)?

Comment: You go wrong way about it. You should pass the form with choices you want it to have to twig instead of setting them in the template. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Symfony forms.  A world which I have now left behind because of these sorts of issues.  Someone else might actually give you a twig based solution but I could never find one.  You will probably need to use a form event listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#customizing-your-form-based-on-the-underlying-data

Comment: e.g. `{'choices': {'foo': { 'attr' : {}, 'value' : true, 'label' : 'foo', }, }, }`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to set the choices in twig?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes, bad backend design; I've only access to the frontend and wanted to use this as a workaround.

Comment: @DarkBee That works? (Haven't tried yet, have you?)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I'm not sure, i just looked into the source of the form_widget what it was expecting.